# Error: However this machine only has: ['/cpu:0']. - but recognizes the 2 gpus

Tags: python, keras, gpu

So I have set up a rig with 2 titan xp's  and am following the example for multi-gpu training from https://github.com/awslabs/keras-apache-mxnet/wiki/Multi-GPU-Model-Training-with-Keras-MXNet.  I have only changed two pieces of code.  `gpus=4` in the model section and `batchsize=32*2` in the batch size section.

I am getting this error which is weird because in the first part it actually shows my gpus (compute etc) but in the last part of the error it only recognizes my cpu:

```
2019-11-19 10:43:32.935282: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-11-19 10:43:32.940953: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2019-11-19 10:43:33.115668: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-11-19 10:43:33.116756: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x27557f0 executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
2019-11-19 10:43:33.116793: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): TITAN Xp COLLECTORS EDITION, Compute Capability 6.1
2019-11-19 10:43:33.116799: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (1): TITAN Xp COLLECTORS EDITION, Compute Capability 6.1
2019-11-19 10:43:33.135701: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 3500025000 Hz
2019-11-19 10:43:33.137115: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x277ba60 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-11-19 10:43:33.137144: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2019-11-19 10:43:33.139168: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device0 with properties: name: TITAN Xp COLLECTORS EDITION major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582 pciBusID: 0000:0a:00.0
2019-11-19 10:43:33.139381: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-11-19 10:43:33.140815: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 1 with properties: name: TITAN Xp COLLECTORS EDITION major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582pciBusID: 0000:41:00.0
2019-11-19 10:43:33.141201: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcudart.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2019-11-19 10:43:33.141268: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcublas.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2019-11-19 10:43:33.141330: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcufft.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcufft.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2019-11-19 10:43:33.141389: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcurand.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcurand.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2019-11-19 10:43:33.141452: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcusolver.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcusolver.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2019-11-19 10:43:33.141512: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcusparse.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcusparse.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2019-11-19 10:43:33.207406: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2019-11-19 10:43:33.207452: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1663] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Skipping registering GPU devices...
2019-11-19 10:43:33.207550: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1181] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-11-19 10:43:33.207568: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1187]      0 1 
2019-11-19 10:43:33.207578: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1200] 0:   N Y 
2019-11-19 10:43:33.207584: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1200] 1:   Y N 
2019-11-19 10:43:33.229007: W tensorflow/compiler/jit/mark_for_compilation_pass.cc:1412] (One-time warning): Not using XLA:CPU for cluster because envvar TF_XLA_FLAGS=--tf_xla_cpu_global_jit was not set.  
 If you want XLA:CPU, either set that envvar, or use experimental_jit_scope to enable XLA:CPU.  To confirm that XLA is active, pass --vmodule=xla_compilation_cache=1 (as a proper command-line flag, not via TF_XLA_FLAGS) or set the envvar XLA_FLAGS=--xla_hlo_profile.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "multi-gpu.py", line 42, in <module>
model = keras.utils.multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=2)
File "/home/gormosity/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/multi_gpu_utils.py", line 184, in multi_gpu_model available_devices))
ValueError: To call `multi_gpu_model` with `gpus=2`, we expect the following devices to be available: ['/cpu:0', '/gpu:0', '/gpu:1']. However this machine only has: ['/cpu:0']. Try reducing `gpus`.
```

nvidia-smi

```
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.87.00    Driver Version: 418.87.00    CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  TITAN Xp COLLEC...  On   | 00000000:0A:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 23%   24C    P8    10W / 250W |    157MiB / 12196MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  TITAN Xp COLLEC...  On   | 00000000:41:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 23%   36C    P5    27W / 250W |    460MiB / 12192MiB |      4%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      3860      C   python3                                      145MiB |
|    1      1253      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            18MiB |
|    1      1282      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          51MiB |
|    1      1650      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           116MiB |
|    1      1781      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         124MiB |
|    1      3860      C   python3                                      145MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: From your log: "Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Skipping registering GPU devices...", this is quite clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message is showing tensorflow as backend (there could be compatibility problem with cuda 10.1 - if you dont compiled it yourself and maybe this is the problem here) and maybe you need to install mxnet-cu101 too (of course if you want to use mxnet as backend, but if not it does not have a sense to use keras-mxnet). You can try to change backend to [mxnet backend](https://github.com/awslabs/keras-apache-mxnet/blob/master/docs/mxnet_backend/installation.md).

Comment: Yep I just found out I need to go back to 10.0

Comment: you can also use community wheels. I compiled tensorflow wheel for cuda 10.1 ... https://github.com/yaroslavvb/tensorflow-community-wheels/issues